# Angular *ngFor displays only part of array

Tags: angular

I want to print an array of items in `li` tag.
The array for example will have 10 elements but I want to print only 4 on mobile devices and 6 on a desktop.

I don't want to use `slice` method to delete non printed elements because in future it should be a slider.

Is `*ngFor` a solution for this?

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
      <div class="producers">
        {{ item }}
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And my TS

```
export class ProducersComponent implements OnInit {

  items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'];

  innerWidth

  itemsToPrint

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if (this.innerWidth < 600) {
      this.itemsToPrint = 4
    } else {
      this.itemsToPrint = 6
    }
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onResize(event)
  }
}
```

I'm checking the window size to change the number of items to print.

How can I us it in the HTML file?

Cheers,

Kuba

Comment: You could use a pipe to filter the values.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Angular `slice` pipe ([docs](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)):

`<li *ngFor="let item of items | slice:0:itemsToPrint+1">`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a getter method.

```
_items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'];

get items() {
    return this._items.slice(0, this.itemsToPrint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pipe for that, that checks either the size of your user screeen, or the user device.

```js
// screen size
transform(items: any): any {
  if (screen.width <= 600) {
    return items.slice(0, 4);
  } else { return items.slice(0, 6) }
}

// device type
transform(items: any): any {
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    return items.slice(0, 4);
  } else { return items.slice(0, 6) }
}
```

The advantages of using a pipe :

1. You don't touch your data, ony how you display them
2. The display logic isn't polluting your component's logic
3. You can use it on every component you want, without duplicating your code
4. You can parametrize it with arguments